# How to Edit Field in Composed Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to edit one field in a group query

I have one table about pay : tPay

```
+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| idPay       | PayDate      | Pay           | Taxes         |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1           | 2018-01-12   | 1000,01       | 50,01         |
| 2           | 2018-01-26   | 1500,01       | 75,01         |
| 3           | 2018-02-04   | 1200,20       | 65,14         |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+
```

from which I made group by month query : qryPay_groupByMonth (QRY#01)

```
SELECT DateSerial(Year([PayDate]),Month([PayDate]),1) AS Month, 
       Sum(tPay.Pay) AS PayOfMonth, 
       Sum(tPaie.Taxes) AS TaxesOfMonth
FROM tPay
GROUP BY DateSerial(Year([DateFinPeriode]),Month([DateFinPeriode]),1);

+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| Month       | PayOfMonth   | TaxesofMonth  | 
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| 2018-01     | 2500.02      | 125.02        | 
| 2018-02     | 1200.20      | 64.14         | 
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I create tTaxesPaid table as follow to join with the previous query

```
+---------+-------------+
| Month   | TaxesPaid   |
+---------+-------------+
| 2018-01 |  125.02     | 
| 2018-02 |   62.04     | 
+---------+-------------+
```

I get the followign query (QRY#02) where TaxesPaid must be an editable field  and TaxesDiif an calculated filed (diff between due taxe and tax paid).

```
SELECT  tTaxesPaid.Month,  
    tTaxesPaid.TaxesPaid, 
    qryPay_groupByMonth.TaxesOfMonth.TaxesOfMonth, 
    Round([TaxesPaid]-[TaxesOfMonth],2) AS TaxesDiff
FROM tTaxesPaid LEFT JOIN qryPay_groupByMonth ON tTaxesPaid.Month = qryPay_groupByMonth.Month;

+---------+-----------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| Month   | Pay       | Taxes      | TaxesPaid (editable) |TaxesDiff (calc) |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| 2018-01 | 2500.02   | 125.02     |  125.02              |                 |
| 2018-02 | 1200.20   | 64.14      |  62.04               | 2.10            |
+---------+-----------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+
```

I always get an error when I tried to edit Taxes in QRY#02 : impossible to update recordset. I try to put every record type to dyn (global update) but it remains uneditable.

Do anyone have an idea to solve this issue ?

Do I need to copy result of QRY#01 in a temporary table to be able to show every field in a single table report and to be able to edit Taxes Paid ?

Comment: Inserting the results of Q1 into a temp table, and joining that with Q2, is indeed a viable alternative. Especially if `DSum` kills performance.

Comment: Curious, what are you trying to update in that resultset? Why not update the source tables?

Comment: User must have all the report data to update TaxesPaid value (to avoid some input mistake). Allowing input value only in tTaxesPaid will remains a not friendly user method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values cannot be edited because a component of the query (specifically your `qryPay_groupByMonth`) uses aggregation. In MS Access, the recordset returned by any query which uses aggregation at some point in its execution is not updateable.

You can avoid this by using a domain aggregate function (such as `DSum`) to calculate the monthly totals, as this is evaluated outside of the execution of the query, meaning that the query remains updateable.

You could alternatively output the aggregated values to a temporary table (either using an append query [`insert into TempTable select ... from ...`] after clearing the contents of the table first; or a make table query [`select ... into TempTable from ...`] after deleting the table if it already exists [`drop TempTable`]); such temporary table could then be joined to your unaggregated query so that the query remains updateable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it but it very slow, is it normal ?

Comment: @ElenGlimois Yes, the domain aggregate functions are slow to evaluate. I've updated my answer to offer another option.

Comment: Thanks Lee. I will try and see if performance is enough for our need.

Comment: I did test between 1st and 2nd method : I won 6 sec in one of complex query !!! Thanks you soo much

Comment: @ElenGlimois Glad to hear it!